# How can I import data from rows and columns of an excel spreadsheet into separate activity.java files?

Tags: java, android, excel

I am working on a time - table application using Android Studio that would provide notification alerts and information of the subjects for the current day. I have 5 activities (namely Monday through Friday). And I have an excel spreadsheet that contains the time - table of the whole week.

I am able to run the activities according to the days of the week. However I am having difficulties to get the data from the spreadsheet.

The layout.xml file of the activity contains 2 columns - one for the name of the subject and the other for the time interval in which it is held.
I want to display one activity per day(like Monday.java to be the activity that runs on Monday) with the data from that row and column from the spreadsheet.

I am a newbie and trying real hard to developing applications. Any and all help would be really appreciated.

Thank you...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your excel file into **CSV** file so you can parse it line by line as a string and use the method *line.split(', ')* that will enable to parse line by line and even get the columns accordingly. You can also use the suitable data structure that suits you.